# update jade input to hapi.js

Tags: node.js, pug, hapi.js

I have a jade template that I have a create user section that adds a user to an orchestrate.io database.  Below that I have a list of all users with a delete and update link.  The delete works fine by passing the key through the URL as res.params.id when it gets to the server.  When I update using the key it does not see the new values from the input fields so I don't get a payload value to use on the server side. How can I update this field?  Here is my code:
Server side -

```
server.route({
   method: 'GET', 
   path: '/update/{id}',
   handler: function(req, reply){
       db.put('users', req.params.id, {
        "name": 'name',
        "password": 'password',
        "email": 'email'
      })
      .then(function (result) {
          reply.redirect('/');
      })
      .fail(function (err) {
          reply('no update');
      });
   }
});
```

Jade Template-

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Last October Weekly Challenge
  body
    div.container
      p This is the main user page. You can create, update, delete and view users.
      form(action='/',method='POST')
        label(for='name') Name
          input(id='name',type='text',value='',placeholder='Enter Name',name='name')
        label(for='password') Password
          input(id='password',type='password',value='',placeholder='Enter Password',name='password')
        label(for='email') Email
          input(id='email',type='email',value='',placeholder='Enter Email',name='email')
        input(id='submit',type='submit',value='Create User',name='submit')
      p Here are the current users:
      table
        each item in items
          tr
            td
              input(type='text' name='update-name' value= item.value.name)
            td
              input(type='text' name='update-password' value= item.value.password)
            td
              input(type='email' name='update-email' value= item.value.email)
            td
              a(href="/delete/" + item.path.key) Delete
            td
              a(href="/update/" + item.path.key) Update
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things that could cause your issue. 1) Your server.route method is "GET" but it should be "POST" to handle/match the form's method attribute; and, 2) You don't have the ID as a hidden field in the form (or as part of the action's URL e.g. form action="/update/12345" method="POST"...).